# Does/Is Matlab Compiler generate/capable of generation C/C++ code before creating executable?

Tags: matlab

Does Matlab Compiler generate (or is capable of generating) C/C++ code equivalent of *.m files which it later compiles into executable? Is it possible? Or does it just create exe without c/c+ step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [MATLAB Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) product, not the [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/). The MATLAB Compiler is about application deployment not code generation.

Comment: I thought it is possible since "mcc" has "-g" option described in the documentation as follows:

***-g Generate Debugging Information***

Include debugging symbol information for the C/C++ code generated by MATLAB Compiler.

Comment: It doesn't generate C/C++ code for everything. In particular, it doesn't necessarily generate code for the M-file itself. But it may do for some of it in order to maximise the performance.